# Parsing Email(Email format is not Fixed) for certain fields in c#

Tags: c#, email

We have a requirement to Parse the email and get certain fields like Name, Address and from email address from the mail body and Header. The Problem lies in the fact that the format of email is not fixed which means that the fields can come in any order in the email body but we only need to get the values of the above mentioned fields.

I am able to get the whole email but not able to understand how to handle the scenario of getting the value from my required fields.

Request you to please have a look and help me out.

Regards
Vineet More

Comment: Can you give us an example email? Is it HTML? POP3, Exchange etc? I've done this in the past. If it's HTML you should use HtmlAgilityPack: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack. Otherwise you will need to use regular expressions. If you have no key-value (in this sense I mean having a string like "Name: [SomeName]" You can use Name: as a key in the regular expression) then you're a bit stuck.

Comment: The mail content is coming in HTML only. I am also using HtmlAgilityPack but we are not able to understand how to fetch the required values from the HTML. As per current Analysis, we found that our fields are always in tables but in html there are multiple tables and none of them have any table id to identify it from others which makes to loop through all the tables(td,tr). So currently stuck over there and not able to understand how to proceed.

Comment: Are the tables in any particular order or random?

Comment: Random..No Pattern or format to rely on..

Comment: Could you give us a copy of the html with some sample data?